# Random Forest classifier class_weight

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have an unbalanced dataset of 200000 descriptions being class 0, and something like 10000 being class 1. However, in my training dataset I have equal number of 'positive' and 'negative' samples, about 8000 each. So now I am confused about how I should properly use the "class_weight" option of the classifier. It seems that it works only if the number of the 'positive' and 'negative' samples in the training data is the same as in the whole dataset. In this case it would be 8000 'positive' and 160000 of 'negative' ones, which is not really feasible. And reducing the number of the 'positive' samples doesn't seem to be a good idea either. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't stratifying your training set? It's usually useful to have a training set representative of your data.

Comment: This question as it seems IMO in current form is more related to the algorithm instead of a programming issue. Please post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ncfirth sorry, could you please elaborate on it a bit? you mean having proportional number of 'positive' class to what I expect to have in the whole dataset? I have these 16000 descriptions, which I have extracted from the whole dataset with different keywords, and basically checked them manually. And now I am trying to extract more descriptions from the whole dataset with machine learning. And I just assume that it is sparse. If you have any idea or paper suggestion, i would be very grateful!

Comment: @VivekKumar probably you are right, or it is even more a conceptual question.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250273/benefits-of-stratified-vs-random-sampling-for-generating-training-data-in-classi)

Answer (score 3):

The `class_weight`option does nothing more than increasing the weight of making an error with the under-represented class. In other words, misclassifying the rare class is punished harsher.

The classifier is likely to perform better on your test set (where both classes are represented equally, so both are equally important), but that is something you can easily verify yourself.

A side-effect is that `predict_proba` returns probabilities which are far away from the actual probabilities. (If you want to understand why, plot the simple average chance and the distribution of predicted scores without and with different `class_weight=`. How do the predicted scores shift?). Depending on your final use-case (classification, ranking, probability estimation) you should consider the choices in your model.

Comment: OP has clarified that both classes are equally represented in his/her *training* set - it is the test set that is imbalanced

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, from the point of view of your *training* set, you don't face a class imbalance issue, so you could very well leave `class_weight` to its default `None` value.

The real issue here and in imbalanced datasets in general (about which you don't provide any info) is if the *cost* of misclassification is the same for both classes. And this is a "businesss" decision (i.e. not a statistics/algorithmic one).

Usually, imbalanced datasets go hand-in-hand with problems with different misclassification costs; medical diagnosis is a textbook example here, since:

1. The datasets are almost by default imbalanced, since healthy people vastly outnumber infected ones
2. We would prefer a false alarm (misclassifying someone as having the disease, while he/she doesn't) rather than a missed detection (misclassifying an infected person as healthy, hence risking his/her life)

So, this is the actual problem you should be thinking about (i.e. even before building your training set).

If, for the *business* problem you are trying to address, there is not any difference between misclassifying a "0" for "1" and a "1" for "0", and given that your training set is balanced, you can proceed without worrying about assigning different class weights...

Comment: thank you, this is very interesting. But it seems like cost framework is not implemented in the scikit-learn implementation of random forest. Or could I somehow use sample_weights for that?

Comment: @student this is a very general discussion on a huge topic, and it cannot be resolved here; I suggest to start googling ruthlessly on class imbalance, imbalanced data, class weights, misclassification cost etc...

Comment: @student you are very welcome (you could also even accept the answer...)